# export libGDX desktop jar file

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to export the game i did in libgdx.
Well i went into the build path of the game and ticked everything.
When i export the jar and double click on it it opens and exists immediately.

It looks like it can't even get to the render method, which means the problem is before.
Any ideas? am i missing something?

Main.java

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Initializing the Window!");
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg;
        cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        cfg.title = "My GDX Game";
        cfg.useGL20 = true;
        cfg.width = (int) 1280;
        cfg.height = (int) 720;
        //cfg.width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
        //cfg.height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
        cfg.resizable = false;
        cfg.fullscreen = false;
        System.err.println("The Window has Initialized");

        System.out.println("Calling the Game!");
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);

    }
}
```

MyGdxGame.java

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.me.mygdxgame.screen.GameScreen;

public class MyGdxGame extends Game {

    public GameScreen game_screen;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        System.out.println("Initializing the game screen!");
        game_screen = new GameScreen(this);

        setScreen(game_screen);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!
if you need more info, no problem just tell me.

Comment: Try running the jar from the command line. It will probably give you a stack trace.

Comment: @RodHyde Thank you so much, I've been asking myself where can i look for the stack trace!

Comment: @RodHyde I fixed it, thanks to you, i tried to load a font named `arial` when its "real name" is `ARIAL` and it caused the bug.